# Is there any possibility of changing the MySQL DB table's field name or adding a new field in Joomla in any project?

Tags: mysql, joomla

Is there any possibility of changing the MySQL DB table's field name or adding a new field in Joomla in any project?

I need this information because I have to apply the Triggers for the tables.. Please Help

Comment: What do you mean by "the table's field name", and where in Joomla do you want to add a new field? Your question doesn't make sense. Please clarify.

Comment: I am In the need of apply triggers on my tables toi get the audit trail, for changes done in any table... For that purpose i need fields of every to be fixed as if the field name changes or new field is added I have to create the all new triggers associated to that table.... I hope its clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core Joomla tables for 1.5 have been stable from 1.5.0 through the current 1.5.15. However, if you add any components to your Joomla installation, you will probably get new tables.

In the past, some components attempted to add fields the core Joomla tables, but most third-party developers have cleaned up their acts. Otherwise, no, the existing core table fields should stay the same.